# Asp.Net Core oData - Post request all properties are null

Tags: c#, post, asp.net-core, odata

I try to setup up a oData controller for my Asp.Net core project.

`Get/GetSingle/Delete/Patch` is working like a charm.

But my post request my incoming model always have all properties set to null.

I am using Asp.Net.Core 2.2 and oData 7.1

```
public async Task<ActionResult<TViewModel>> Post(TViewModel item)
{           
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    try
    {
        var addedEntity = await _manager.AddAsync(_mapper.Map<TModel>(item));
        return Ok(_mapper.Map<TViewModel>(addedEntity));
    }
    catch (CreateException)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }
}
```

Thats my model:

```
public class UserViewModel : IViewModel
{
    public Guid? Id { get; set; }
    public string SecurityStamp { get; set; }

    public Gender? Gender { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<string> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my request:

[image]

And this is my result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify `[FromBody]` for the controller parameter so the framework can bind correctly to your model.  Please see the documentation on [Model Binding in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

Try:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<TViewModel>> Post([FromBody] TViewModel item)
{
    // your code
}
```